# Change ZingChart legend behavior (highlight series on legend click, rather than toggle)

Tags: javascript, charts

I have a line graph and the default behavior for hovering over a legend item is to highlight the series and the series disappears when clicking  the legend item.  However, hovering doesn't work on mobile devices so I'd like to get rid of the disappearing series and just make both hovering and clicking lead to highlighting the series.

It looks like there is an event in the API that can register a click on a legend item (legend_item_click):
https://www.zingchart.com/docs/api/events/#zingchart__events__legend_item_click
but I'm not sure how to use it in my chart to change this default behavior.  Can anyone provide example code for switching from the toggling off/on the series to highlighting the series?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There currently is no way to do this out of the box for clicking on a legend item but this functionality does exist on legend item hover: https://www.zingchart.com/docs/tutorials/chart-elements/interactive-chart-legend/#interactive-features-legend-highlight

If you own a license or purchase premium support hours the Zingchart team would be able to implement this into their library as it basically already exists, just not connected.